# boolen operation is not carried over into stl file upon export

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I have attached my modelling approach for cutting out a cylinder with another and then exporting it. For some reason, the stl file does not contain the final cut-out, instead it shows the 2 cylinders.
This is the first time this has happened to me. Cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either *delete* the second cylinder or select *Selection Only* in the export function and make sure the first cylinder is selected.  Hiding the second cylinder from the viewport isn't sufficient to keep it from being exprted.

Comment: That works!! Thanks